# How to change text in sidebar dynamically based on component I click on?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to make a timeline website. I would like to click on a Interval component (such as Russo-Persian War in the code below) and a text-description to show on the sidebar. There is currently no text description set. The sidebar is currently set to "Lorem Ipsum". How can I dynamically change the text in the sidebar based on the Interval component I click on? Thank you.

Here is my code:
Sidebar.vue

```
    <div id="side-bar">
        <hr />
        {{text}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
    data() {
        return {
            text: `Lorem Ipsum`,
        }
    },
    methods: {
           },
})
</script>
```

Helper.js

```
export class Mark {
  name = ''
  tags = []
  constructor(date) {
    this.year = date
}
}
/* An interval consist of two marks (dates) in time-history */
export class Interval {
  from = null
  to = null
  subIntervals = null
  name = ''
  i18n = null
  tags = []
  constructor() {
if (arguments.length === 1) {
      let data = arguments[0]
      this.from = new Mark(data.from)
      this.to = new Mark(data.to)
      if (data.subIntervals !== undefined) {
        this.subIntervals = data.subIntervals
      }
      this.i18n = {
        messages: {
          es: { message: { title: data.title } }
        }
      }
    } else {
this.from = arguments[0]
      this.to = arguments[1]
    }
  }
}
/* A 'Timeline' consist of a 'name' and a
 * property 'events', which consists of an ordered list
 * of 'Interval's AND/OR 'Mark's (or even other 'Timeline's) */
export class Timeline {
  events = []
  name = ''
  tags = []
  constructor(_name) {
    this.name = _name
  }
}
```

Data.js

```
import { Interval, Timeline, century } from './Helper'
...
new Interval({
    title: '1800s',
    from: 1800,
    to: 1899,
  })

let lower = new Timeline()

let ninteenthcentury = new Timeline('1900s')
ninteenthcentury.events.push(
  new Interval({
    title: 'Russo-Persian War',
    from: 1804,
    to: 1813,
  }),

  new Interval({
    title: 'Russo-Turkish War',
    from: 1806,
    to: 1812,
  })
(etc...)
)
lower.events.push(
ninteenthcentury
)
export { lower }
```

Format.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="interval"
    :style="{
      width: width + 'px',
      marginLeft: marginLeft + 'px',
      display: width < 51 ? 'none' : 'flex'
    }"
    :title="title">
    <span v-on:click= "" class="name" >{{$t('message.title')}}</span>

    
    
    
    <!-- sub intervals -->
    <div class="lane" v-if="data.subIntervals">
      <interval
        v-for="(subInterval, index) in data.subIntervals"
        :key="index"
        :data="subInterval"
        :left="last(index)"
        :ratio="ratio" />
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'interval',
  props: ['data', 'ratio', 'left'],
  i18n: {
  },
  created: function() {
    if (this.data.i18n) {
      this.$i18n.setLocaleMessage('es', this.data.i18n.messages.es)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    last(index) {
      if (index > 0) {
        return this.data.subIntervals[index - 1].to.year
      }
      return this.data.from.year
    },
  },
  computed: {
    marginLeft() {
      if (this.left) {
        return Math.abs(this.left - this.data.from.year) * this.ratio
      }
      return 0
    },
    width() {
        return (this.data.to.year - this.data.from.year) * this.ratio
    },
    title() {
      return this.$i18n.t('message.title') + ` (${this.data.from.year},${this.data.to.year})`
    },
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should consider migrating your helper to vuex, using store features will help you in every thing.

You will have all intervals in one array and, for instance, have a prop in your store for currentInterval that changes every time you click an interval on the timeline. You can achieve this by dispatching a vuex action to the store that will mutate the state of your prop, ex currentInterval.

In the component where you show the current interval data you will ...mapGetters from the store that will always return that prop currentInterval of the store.

More information about store management here: [enter link description here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#single-state-tree)